# How to change NavBar colour of MasterMainPage in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, navbar, background-color

I'm building a Xamarin cross-platform App!

The problem is I want to change the colour of `NavigationBar` of `MainPage` which is `MasterPage` with a drawer menu in it.

I tried with this code to change the colour but an extra bar appears on NavBar which I don't Want to.

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())

        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00477f"),
            BarTextColor = Color.White,
        };
```

**ScreenShots:**
These Screenshots shows what the problem I'm facing!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbXie.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuA1A.png]

Comment: Change your (new MainPage()) to other page name

MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())

        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00477f"),
            BarTextColor = Color.White,
        };

Comment: @Narendra Sharma I also tried  but this effects the master drawer menu. after changing to other page name drawer menu vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, when you assign `App.xaml`'s `MainPage`, a `NavigationPage`, it shows it's own NavigationBar. Under the hood, your `MasterDetailPage` also shows the NavigationBar. Thus, you are viewing two NavigationBars.

Go to your `MainPage.xaml.cs` backend page and in the Constructor, write the line:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Thus, your `MainPage.xaml.cs` should look like :

```
public MainPage()
{
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    InitializeComponent();
    ......
}
```

This will hide the NavigationBar of MasterDetailPage.

Answer (score 0):

The NavigationPage has a BarBackgroundColor property which you can set.

[Referred this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/)

```
var nav = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage { Title = "Page" } );
nav.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
```