# NavBar is not appearing on DetailPage in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, navbar

I'm building a Xamarin cross-platform App !

**App coantain 3 Pages :**

`MainPage` ( MasterDetailPage with drawer meun )

`HomePage` (ContentPage )

`DetailGetData` (ContentPage )

`Homepage` displays list of items in listview and every item is selectable and shows its detail in next page which is in `DetailGetData`

The problem is when it shows detail in next page the `NavBar` is not appearing and I don't know why help me through this!

ScreenShot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1csoB.png

**DetailGetData.xaml:**

```
<ContentPage 
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MSPL.Views.DetailGetData">


<Frame  BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White" 
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        Padding="0" Margin="0" HeightRequest="250" WidthRequest="240">




    <Grid Padding="0" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Image Source="ford.jpg" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

        <Label  Text="{Binding employee_name }" TextColor="#00477f" x:Name="empname" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label  Text="{Binding employee_age }" TextColor="#00477f" x:Name="age" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label  Text="{Binding employee_salary }" TextColor="#00477f" x:Name="salary" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

**DetailGetData.xaml.cs:**

```
using MSPL.MenuItems;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MSPL.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DetailGetData : ContentPage
    { 

    public GetData thisData;

    public DetailGetData()
    {

    }

    public DetailGetData (GetData _data)
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingList(_data);
        thisData = _data;
    }

    public void BindingList(GetData data)
    {
        empname.Text = data.employee_name;
        age.Text = data.employee_age;
        salary.Text = data.employee_salary;
    }     
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it has something to do with the code you got here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454645/how-to-change-navbar-colour-of-mastermainpage-in-xamarin? Not to be rude here, but I think it can be very valuable to understand what a piece of code does instead of just copy and pasting it and open a next question whenever something doesn't work again.

Comment: is your ContentPage wrapped in a NavigationPage?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Both are different questions and Not to be rude here,  stackoverflow is the platform where you can ask question related to your work which you don't understand so people around world can help you!

Comment: @Jason No, How to wrap it in NavigationPage ?

Comment: in your MasterDetail, when you assign the Detail, wrap it in a NavigationPage.  `Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage));`.

Comment: @Jason Thankyou It works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Navigation bar only appears when your page in wrapped in a Navigation page.  From your MasterDetail you would do something like this

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage));
```