# Xamarin MasterDetailsPage with back buttons

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

Im working on a project were I have to have a side menu. So I chose a MasterDetailsPage layout.

Problem is that my first page in the side menu is my main page and I want to have a backbutton to the main page if I navigate to any of the other pages in the side menu.

What I see is that every other view has a hamburger menu instead of a backbutton.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In `MasterDetail` page, when you select any item in the side menu, it simply replaces the current `DetailPage` with the selected item Page. To change this behavior:

First make sure in your `App.xaml.cs` file you load `MainPage` inside the `NavigationPage` as follows:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

You may see the two navigation bars on top of the screen. Follow [this step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454645/how-to-change-navbar-colour-of-mastermainpage-in-xamarin/55455855#55455855) to hide one.

Now on click event of the SideMenu item, you should write the following code to navigate your other page with Back arrow.

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new YourTargetPage());
```

This will push the page into the page navigation stack instead of replacing the `DetailPage` of the `MasterDetailPage`..